# python logging to seprate files from one class

Tags: python, logging

I need to add logging functionality to one class, that would log to separate files according to which of its methods was called , but I can't find much discussion or documentation about this.

I have 4 files: `01.log 02.log 03.log 04.log`, a logger and I have a class with already implemented functions. For sake of not overcomplicating it let' s say that I have simplified class like this and I am adding those lines, that contain call to logger.

```
class MyClass():
    def function1():
        logger.info('function 1 was called')
        #doing something 
    def function2(arg):
        logger.info('function 2 was called')
        #doing something        
        if arg is None:
            logger.error('arg of function 2 was none')
        #doing something 
    def function3():
        logger.info('function 3 was called')
    def function4():
        logger.debug('debugging info')
```

now, what need to do is to send function1 logs only to file 01.log, function2 logs only to 02.log and so on.

I was thinking about using 3 FileHandlers and filters, that would somehow let only those LogRecords from their function of interest pass, but I don't quite understand how to utilize the funcName attribute of LogRecord. Another idea is to have more loggers - for each function one - and I would set their Propagate to false. However, this seems like an overkill to me.

Is there any better solution? If not, how can I properly use filters(and probably LogRecord attribute funcName) to do it?
Thanks

Comment: You could make different handlers for each function and add the appropriate one at the beginning of the function call, then remove it at the end of the function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler

Comment: Or you could use a decorator like this: https://git.io/vwIVL

Comment: @Eli that looks really good, thanks. Just wondering, how about thread safeness? What if separate threads call 2 functions at once? Will both handlers be used?

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't be thread safe

Comment: Thanks anyway, at least I learned something more about decorators. I think I figured this out today when I was tinkering with filters. Using funcName and threadName attributes of LogRecords for filtering in handlers I managed to direct output to wanted files.